# Create a vector of numbers, mixture of consecutive and non-consecutive, in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I want to generate a vector (used as indices) such as one below generated in Matlab:

```
idx = [1:60,71:120,181:240]' % it is used as indices in A = B(idx,:,:)
```

How to rewrite the code above in Python

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you would use `idx` for specifically?

Comment: just concatenate ranges: `list(range(1,60) + list(range(71,120)) + list(range(181,240))` - if you just want those numbers in a list ...

Comment: @secs Thanks for your prompt answer！

Comment: @Joe Patten: I have modified my post.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.r_`:

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.r_[1:60,61:120,181:240]
```

Yields:

```
[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73
  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91
  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188
 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206
 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224
 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239]
```

Note that ranges in Python are not inclusive of the upper bound opposed to Matlab, as well as the fact that Python is indexed from 0, whereas Matlab is indexed from 1.

Comment: You gives a neat solution that is really what I want to see!!